# Can I safely pass null to Function.apply in place of thisArg argument?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

To make public API of SWF more reliable, I usually wrap callbacks in closure with try/catch block:

```
private function addCallback(functionName:String, closure:Function):void {
    ExternalInterface.addCallback(functionName, wrapEventHandler(closure));
}

private function wrapEventHandler(closure:Function):Function {
    var self:Main = this;
    return function(...arguments):* {
        try {
            return closure.apply(self, arguments);
        } catch (error:Error) {
        // Print error report here
        }
    }
}
```

When exception occurs in 'closure', error report will be printed.

I noticed that it works fine even when using 'null' instead of 'self':

```
closure.apply(null, arguments);
```

Is it safe to use 'null' in this case?

Callback I register with ExternalInterface aren't static functions; they use Main's class fields.

It works just fine with null, NaN and self. I couldn't find any problems with using NaN/null.

Comment: [This](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) article on function invocation helped me a lot to understand what I should be using as thisArg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the `this` argument to [`apply()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply%28%29) is optional, and the parameter default value is `NaN`.

> #### *Parameters*
>
> `thisArg:*` (default = NaN) — The object to which the function is
>   applied.

Likewise with, [`call()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#call%28%29):

> You can pass the value `null` for the `thisObject` parameter to invoke a
>   function as a regular function and not as a method of an object.
>
> For example, the following function invocations are equivalent:
>
> ```
> Math.sin(Math.PI / 4)   
> Math.sin.call(null, Math.PI / 4)
> ```

Comment: Is it safe to use NaN/null when closure isn't static function like Math.sin, but method?

Comment: @FredK If that method does not use any fields of a class in which it's located, then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: Vesper, all callbacks I register with ExternalInterface use at least one Main's class field. So 'self' is the way to go?

Comment: I came to the conslusion that using NaN is safe for non-static methods. See "Bound methods" section: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f36.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa5

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238962/function-apply-not-using-thisarg-parameter