# Function.call( thisObject ) not working on AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, function, call, this

I have a very simple code here that explains the difference I found between AS2 and AS3 when using the **call** method of a function.

```
var a = {name:"a"}
var b = {name:"b"}

function c()
{
    trace(this.name)
}


c()         // AS2: undefined   AS3: root1
c.apply(a)  // AS2: a           AS3: root1
c.apply(b)  // AS2: b           AS3: root1
```

How can I force AS3 to respect the thisObject argument in AS3?

Here is Adobe Documentation
"http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply()"

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238962/function-apply-not-using-thisarg-parameter/7260369#7260369) may also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to recognize that `Functions` are different from `Methods`. `Methods` are bound to the objects that they are defined in, whereas `Functions` are not bound to any object.

When you are using `apply` or even `call` on a method you are extracting it from its instance, but it will always be bound to the object.

So in your example if `c()` is inside an object, that is why you are not seeing `thisObject` change.

From adobe on Methods:

> Methods are functions that are part of a class definition. Once an
>   instance of the class is created, a method is bound to that instance.
>   Unlike a function declared outside a class, a method cannot be used
>   apart from the instance to which it is attached

**Now** if you want to be able to change the `thisObject` you can create a function outside of the object and pass the new `thisObject` parameter. Here's a very basic example:

```
class myClass {
    public function myBoundFunction():void {
        trace( "Bound to: " + this );
    }
}

//declared outside the class
function unboundFunction():void {
    trace( "Unbound: " + this.name );
}
```

Then instantiating and applying the functions with `thisObject` parameter:

```
var c:myClass = new myClass();
//bound function call
c.myBoundFunction.apply( this );

//unbound call  
unboundFunction.apply( this );
```

**Output:**

```
Bound to: [object myClass]
Unbound: root1
```