# AS3: Calling superclass method instead of subclass instance's override?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, overriding, subclass, superclass

Let's say we have superclass A and subclass B:

```
public class A {
    public function f() {...}
}

public class B extends A {
    override public function f() {...}
}
```

Superclass A has a method called f, and subclass B has an override for f. Now I have an instance of class B:

```
var b:B = new B();
```

Is it impossible to call b's superclass version of f, by doing something like b.super.f()? Without writing a method for B that explicitly calls super.f();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: *Kind of*, but it's not fun

Long answer: I originally thought that it would be possible using the `Function` object and either `apply()` or `call()`, but the even though the docs (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply()) say that you can pass another object, it doesn't work, it's always bounds to the declared class.

```
...
public function foo():void
{
    trace( this );
}
...

var func:Function = a.foo;
func.apply( b ); // traces a
```

After stumbling around a bit, I came across this SO answer ([Function.apply not using thisArg parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238962/function-apply-not-using-thisarg-parameter)), which explains why this isn't working (tldr; it's because methods are bounds to their instances on creation).

It's possible to hack around this using `prototype` though. You just need to declare your class like this:

```
public dynamic class A 
{
    prototype.foo = function():void
    {
        trace( this );
    }       
}
```

NOTE the function declaration style and the `dynamic` property on the class. The `foo()` function won't be bound on creation, so you can call it like:

```
var func:Function = a.foo;
func.apply( a ); // traces a
func.apply( b ); // traces b
```

This works even if `B` declares another method called `foo`.

In short, to get it to work/downsides:

- You need to make your classes dynamic (thus bigger, and able to add whatever param you wanted)
- You need to hack the declaration of the function itself
- You need access to a base class `Function` object (though you can just call `( new A ).foo`)
- You don't get code completion

All in all, it's probably easier to create a method on `B` to expose the `A` functionality (or if you find yourself need to call this from outside, just break it off to a dedicated function, where it's treated like any other public func)